# Zend framework query where clause

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have the following query for searching the tables by car model no and category name

```
SELECT * FROM CARS as car 
LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES as cat 
ON cat.car_id = car.car_id 
WHERE (car.model_no LIKE '%GT V8%') OR (cat.name LIKE '%GT V8%')
```

I am using zend framework so I have  the query like this so far in my model

```
$sql = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('car'=>$this->_name), array())
            ->joinLeft(array('cat'=>'categories'), 'cat.car_id=car.car_id', array())
```

then in where clause

I do like this

```
$sql->where('car.model_no LIKE ?', '%'.$query['search'].'%')
    ->where('cat.name LIKE ?', '%'.$query['search'].'%')
```

but that output like

```
WHERE (car.model_no LIKE '%GT V8%') AND (cat.name LIKE '%GT V8%')
```

I just can't find a way to replace AND with OR.. Is there anyway to do that in zend_db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [orWhere](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) (Example #19)

```
$sql->where('car.model_no LIKE ?', '%'.$query['search'].'%')->orWhere('cat.name LIKE ?', '%'.$query['search'].'%')
```

From the docs:

> If you need to combine terms together using OR, use the orWhere() method. This method is used in the same way as the where() method, except that the term specified is preceded by OR, instead of AND.

Comment: wow I couldn't find that in their doc haha :) thanks a lot man :)